# Get Values of Pixels Inside Polygon (MODIS)

Tags: gdal, remote-sensing, modis

I am working on a problem where I have polygons for features and I want look at daily data from MODIS on, and I am looking for suggestions on how to determine which pixels it is that I need to look at. I have tried gdallocationinfo however this only gives me a single pixel, and I am looking to get all the pixels that are at least 80% inside of the polygon. I am looking for a coding based solution as I have about 8,000 polygons I'm looking to process.

One other thing that makes the process a bit more complicated, the MODIS bands I'm using at at 500m resolution, while the cloud-mask for it is at 1km (int the state_1km band) so I will need to keep the two data-sets in alignment throughout the process.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I came up with was to put one of the rasters into postGIS with raster2pgsql, and then use this script, which took about 9 hours to run.

```
INSERT INTO modis.pixels (SELECT t1.v, t2.v, ST_PixelASPolygon(raster.rast, t1.v, t2.v)
FROM modis.raster
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 2400) as t1(v)
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 2400) as t2(v));
```

Then I built an index which took about 2 and a half minutes, and finally used this script which was taking about 30ms/polygon.

```
INSERT INTO modis.polygon_pixels(
SELECT polygon_id::integer, 'h10v03'::text AS tile, x::smallint, y::smallint,(ST_Area(ST_TRANSFORM(ST_Intersection(st_transform(boundary,96842), geom), 3857))/ST_AREA(ST_TRANSFORM(geom, 3857)) * 100)::smallint AS coverage
FROM polygon.boundary
JOIN modis.pixels
    ON ST_Intersects(st_transform(boundary,96842), geom));
```